# printing the first 100 primes using arrays (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

I am fairly new at this and was wondering if what I am doing is correct. I have to print the first 100 prime numbers using arrays in C++. My code outputs a lot of numbers alongside the primes that I need. Was wondering what exactly is wrong. Thank you in advance.

```
int myPrimes[100];
int i,j,count=1,b=0;

for(i=3;i>0;++i)
{
    for(j=2;j<=i/2;++j)
    {
        if(i%j==0){//checking if composite
            b=1;//if composite, goes to the next number
            break;
        }
    }

    if(b==0)//if prime
    {
        //cout<<"\n"<<i;//print the number
        myPrimes[count]=i;
        count++;//counter goes up 1 to go to the next number
    }

    b=0;//resets b so you can run the loop again
    if(count==101)//after the counter reaches 100, exits the program
        break;
}

for(int i=0;i<=sizeof(myPrimes);i++){
  cout << myPrimes[i] << endl;
}

return 0;
```

My Outputs after the 100 primes:

[outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as3mK.png)

Comment: Think about what `sizeof(myPrimes)` actually gives you.

Comment: The `sizeof` operator give you the size of the operand in ***bytes***. If `int` is a 32-bit type (the most common) then that's 4 bytes. That mens your array `myPrimes` will be `4 * 100` bytes large, or `400`. Now think about that in your loop where you print the values of `myPrimes`.

Comment: Also remember that array-indexes are zero-based. So an array of `100` elements will have indexes from `0` to `99` (inclusive). That means your condition `if(count==101)` will break out of the loop when you have already written to index `100` in the array. Going out of bounds of an array leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

Print first 100 primes using arrays

```cpp
int primes[100] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61,
 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157,
 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257,
 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367,
 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 
 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541};

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    cout << myPrimes[i] << endl;
}
```

### **P e r f e c t**

Just kidding, ignoring me

---

Provide normal answer

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool isPrime(int number) {
    if (number <= 1) return false;

    for (int i = 2; i * i <= number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main() {
    const int numOfPrimes = 100;
    int primes[numOfPrimes];
    int index = 0;
    int number = 2;

    while(index < numOfPrimes) {
        if(isPrime(number)) {
            primes[index] = number;
            index++;
        }
        number++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numOfPrimes; i++){
        cout << myPrimes[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

haven't checked, no compile

---

The midden part can change to :

```cpp
while(index < 100) {
    if(isPrime(number++)) {
        primes[index++] = number;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the `sizeof(myPrimes)` to `100` and also include myPrimes[0]=2 as it is prime number.

The `sizeof` operator give you the size of the operand in bytes.

```
// Recursive program to check if a given linked list is palindrome
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int myPrimes[100];
int i,j,count=1,b=0;
myPrimes[0]=2; // 2 is also prime numer include this in the myPrimes array
for(i=3;i>0;++i)
{
    for(j=2;j<=i/2;++j)
    {
        if(i%j==0){//checking if composite
            b=1;//if composite, goes to the next number
            break;
        }
    }

    if(b==0)//if prime
    {
        //cout<<"\n"<<i;//print the number
        myPrimes[count]=i;
        count++;//counter goes up 1 to go to the next number
    }

    b=0;//resets b so you can run the loop again
    if(count==101)//after the counter reaches 100, exits the program
        break;
}

for(int i=0;i<100;i++){ // use 100 instead of sizeof(myPrimes)
  cout << myPrimes[i] << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use 100 instead of `sizeof(myPrimes)`.

sizeof should not be used to get number of elements here. A separate parameter for array size (or length) should be used. Because sizeof operator give you the size of the operand in bytes.

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){ 
  cout << myPrimes[i] << endl;
}
```